# Python launcher not responding after closing VNC (mac)

Tags: python, vnc, openai-gym

I'm trying to create a simple program using universe by openai but every time I close the VNC, the python launcher doesn't respond anymore and I have to force quit it. What can I do to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it closes without crashing if I type in the terminal ctrl+c instead of ctrl+z as I did before.